# How to show current user type in symfony 1.4

Tags: user-controls, symfony-1.4

In my symfony 1.4 project I have 3 types of user (admin,moderator,reader) with different types of access. 
How can I show which type of user is current user?

Comment: How is the type determined by? It comes from a type column, a user group, a permission (credential)?

Comment: from a user group and permission

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have 2 options:

- to get user permissions you can call `$sf_user->getGuardUser()->getAllPermissionNames()` or `$sf_user->getGuardUser()->hasPermission('admin')`
- when a user logs in his permissions will be credentials. You can call `$sf_user->getCredentials()` or `$sf_user->hasCrednetial()` in templates to get the current user's credentials. E.g. you can write `<?php echo implode(', ', $sf_user->getCredentials() ?: array()) ?>` to list all user credentials. If a user can have other credentials and you don't want to display those use `hasCredential()` instead. If you need some custom logic and want to keep it in an action or a component you should use `$this->getUser()->...` instead of `$sf_user->...`.